# ActiveMQ Detect new Consumer Topic

Tags: java, activemq-classic, broker

I have a standard activeMQ Broker

```
    private static String localVMurl = "vm://localhost";

    broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector(localVMurl); 
    broker.start();
```

and all is well.  what my goal is that a consumer connects to the broker with a specific topic.  Once this connection is *detectd* the broker will either pass along messages if a Producer is actively producing to the topic, OR the broker will start a new Producer for that specific topic.  However to do this, i need to someone detect when a new consumer connects and requests a specific topic.

my basic consumer code:

```
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(remoterURL);
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.setClientID("clinet1");
    connection.start();

    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Topic topic = session.createTopic("some_topic");
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
    consumer.setMessageListener(new MyMessageListener());
```

and I can see in the Broker logs:

```
  <161005 11:03:41> [.0.1:64433@5001] DEBUG tRegion - localhost adding destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.some_topic
```

So i know the consumer connects, and subscribes to this topic, I just need to catch that event somehow.

Any thoughts as to how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Advisory Message is what you need. each time you got a message with this code this means you have new consumer starting or stopping.

doc http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

example:

```
    //org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport.getDestinationAdvisoryTopic(Destination)
Destination advisoryDestination = AdvisorySupport.getConsumerAdvisoryTopic(topic )
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(advisoryDestination);
consumer.setMessageListener(this);

public void onMessage(Message msg){
    if (msg instanceof ActiveMQMessage){
        try {
            ActiveMQMessage aMsg =  (ActiveMQMessage)msg;
            ConsumerInfo consumer = (ConsumerInfo) aMsg.getDataStructure();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("Failed to process message: " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to listen on the Broker, not on the consumer.  the broker doesn't know which topic the consumer will be subscribing to ahead of time.  this doesn't look like what i want ?

Comment: can you explain please, what i understood is **So i know the consumer connects, and subscribes to this topic, I just need to catch that event somehow.**  and my code connect to the broker and listen on it, what do you mean by **i need to listen on the Broker, not on the consumer.**

Comment: if you need this event without knowing the destination in advance you can replace `Destination advisoryDestination = AdvisorySupport.getConsumerAdvisoryTopic(topic );` by `Topic advisoryDestination = session.createTopic("ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.*");` to be notified for any subscription to any topic in the broker and with ConsumerInfo you can retrieve another informations like destination of the consumer `consumer.getDestination();`

Comment: i have a broker in code, with no producers and no topics.  once a consumer connects to the broker looking to subscribe to a specific topic, i want the broker to spawn a producer connected to that topic.  to do this i need the detect when a consumer connects to the broker, once that happens then the broker can spawn the relevant producer.  does that make sense ?

Comment: sorry but i dont understand the definition of spawn and **spawn the relevant producer** :) can you use another term

Comment: nevermind i figured it out.  in the broker itself i need a consumer of AdvisoryTopic messgaes, from there I can handle it.  thanks!

Comment: Yes this my last proposition

Comment: agreed, it wasnt clear where that consumer should be placed, but now I've got it and everything is working thanks for your help!

Comment: Does anyone know how to find if the advisory message indicates that the consumer has started or stopped? thx

Comment: @beta-brad certainly, here http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html